# how to update a custom component in wix using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, velo

I'm working on a wix site using custom HTML and javascript.
[image]

Although I know the block's id is html2, I cannot update the innerhtml from the javascript below it.  it won't udpate.
I know the value is valid.   Why can I not access html2.innerHTML?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use Wix Text Element to display the text and change it using `$w('#html2').text = stardate;`?

Comment: greetings.  I appreciate the help.  I get this error when using your recommendation: Property 'text' does not exist on type 'HtmlComponent'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the Wix text element if you just want to display the text and call,
   `$w('#html2').text = stardate;`
2. You can use [postmessage](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/htmlcomponent/postmessage) api to send message to your embedded html and receive it by [onmessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/message_event) in your embedded html code.

Comment: greetings.  I appreciate the help.  I get this error when using your recommendation: Property 'text' does not exist on type 'HtmlComponent'.

Comment: You have to use Text Element in order to change [text](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/text/text)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the native API with `document.querySelector('#html2')`. Additionally, avoid using `var` if not necessary. If it doesn't work, please check whether the `onReady` function is functioning correctly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you Brock.  apparently my wix is not finding the dom.  document is causing this eror: Cannot find name 'document'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to include 'dom'.

Comment: That means you need to edit compilerOptions:{"lib":["dom"]}

Comment: And it's $w('#html2').html instead of innerHtml